# Is it possible to detect if a component was just added to the page in the Experience Editor?

Tags: experience-editor, presentation

I would like to show some message in my component in case this component was just added in the Experience Editor, but the item is not saved yet.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by checking if the current rendering is contained in the list of renderings of the current item.

```cshtml
@{
    Guid currentRenderingId =
        Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.UniqueId;

    DeviceItem device = Sitecore.Context.Device;
    RenderingReference[] renderings =
        Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.GetRenderings(device, true);

    bool renderingIsSaved =
        renderings.Any(
            r => new Guid(r.UniqueId) == currentRenderingId);
}

@if (renderingIsSaved == false)
{
    <div class="unsaved-rendering">
        This rendering is not saved yet.
    </div>
}
```

The above example is for MVC; the code should be similar in case you use WebForms.

Comment: thanks, seems like no standard API, need to add it to extensions class

Comment: @Arbejdsglæde That's a good idea. Also, to prevent performance degradation, I would wrap the code above into the following check: `if(Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor) { ... }`.

Comment: it goes without saying